# Set Theory and .NET

Tags: .net, ienumerable, set-theory

Recently I came across a situation where set theory and set math fit what I was doing to the letter (granted there was an easier way to accomplish what I needed - i.e. LINQ - but I didn't think of that at the time). However I didn't know of any generic set libraries. Granted IEnumerables provide some set operations (Union, etc.), but nothing like Intersection or set comparison. Can anyone point out something that fits here? Something that implements set math using a generic type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is `HashSet<T>` in the framework (3.5+) that does what you need. .NET 4 also introduced `SortedSet<T>` and a common interface `ISet<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

System.Collections.Generic.HashSet has a number of set operations including Subset, Superset,Intersection,Union etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx

I hope this helps

joe